# multiple button close not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a datepicker and dates are displayed in textfield with button close(x).
On Selecting the date from datepicker, will add date as shown,

But close button is not working, 
on clicking close, should remove the specific date field.
link
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-http-zhj4f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: In textareaHandler() when I console the val . why it is printing 12-02-2020 ? and for the function buttonHanlder() you have to provide default value rather than null

Comment: @DeepKakkar thanks for reply, did changes in code

Comment: @Senthil There seems to be a problem with your onChange method. I changed your onChange handler to how the docs do and it works. Check it out https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-wilbur-cnbnr

Answer (score 0):

Change your code a little bit.

```
<DatePicker
     locale="en-GB"
     onChange={this.buttonHanlder}
     value={this.state.closedate}
/>
```

And in your **buttonHandler** method, use the below code

```
buttonHanlder = value => {
    if (value) {
        var dateformat = [
            ("0" + value.getDate()).slice(-2) +
            "-" +
            ("0" + (value.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
            "-" +
            value.getFullYear()
        ];
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            closedate: value,
            closedatearr: [...prevState.closedatearr, ...dateformat]
        }));
    } else {
        this.setState({
            closedate: ''
        });
    }
};
```

Reason to do so: When you click on **X**(close button) react-date-picker calls **buttonHandler** with null value which means that user has cleared out the date. So you need to handle null value according to your requirements.